# Если ли разница при определении типа вектора через указатель или без?

Tags: c++, vector, delete

Есть ли разница в расположении ресурсов в памяти, и работы с ней в этих 2х случаях, и какой из них предпочитать?

1)

```cpp
vector<std::vector<T*>*> *values = new vector<vector<T*>*>(1000,new vector<T>(1000, new T()));
```

или так

2)

```cpp
vector<std::vector<T>> *values = new vector<vector<T>>(1000,vector<T>(1000,T()));
```

если есть разница, то как очищать память?

для первого случая

```cpp
for(auto a = 0;a<values->size();a++){
    for(auto b = 0;b<values[a].size();b++){
       delete values[a][b];
    }
    delete values[a];
}
delete values;
```

или так?

```cpp
delete values;
```

Comment: Лучше голые указатели в C++ вообще не использовать, только когда доступ к C-апи нужен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом случае у вас

```
vector<std::vector<T*>*> *values = 
    new vector<vector<T*>*>(1000,new vector<T>(1000, new T()));
```

все 1000 элементов первого вектора будут *одним и тем же указателем* на вектор, в котором будет храниться 1000 одинаковых указателей *на одно и то же значение* типа `T`!

И вообще - куда меньше проблем с выделением-освобождением памяти будет во втором случае, так что используйте его (и без указателя!):

```
vector<std::vector<T>> values(1000,vector<T>(1000,T{}));
```

Если зачем-то (зачем?...) вам позарез нужен указатель - ну, тогда

```
vector<std::vector<T>> *values = 
    new vector<vector<T>>(1000,vector<T>(1000,T()));
...
delete values;
```

Но особого смысла не вижу.

Освобождение памяти в первом случае - если вы его исправите - слишком большое и сложное, одно это лишает смысла весь код (да и работать с такой структурой - запутаетесь в разыменованиях). Не для того вектора делали :)

P.S. Еще - в первом случае лишнее косвенное обращение (и далеко не одно!) в принципе вносит свой вклад и приводит к уменьшению производительности...

Answer (score 2):

Технически, разницы нет - так как вектор хранит данные не внутри своего объекта, а на куче, что в первом, что во втором случае, данные не будут лежать в памяти одним большим куском подряд.

Второй случай будет просто запутывать программиста и провоцировать трудноуловимые ошибки (множество которых вы и наделали)

Для некоторых алгоритмов на некоторых данных более предпочтительно держать все данные в памяти одним большим куском (когда все данные имеют по размеру около мегабайта (зависит от CPU, некоторые могучие XEONы могут и 60 мегабайт в кэше удержать) и могут уместится в кэш процессора).

В таком случае, лучше всего сделать:

```
std::vector<T> wad(width*height)
```

А индексацию организовать искусственно:

```
auto& item = wad[i+j*width]
```

Comment: А что такое `std::vector<>`?

Comment: Условность. Туда можно написать какой угодно тип.

Comment: В первом случае при обращении к конечному элементу еще и добавляются несколько лишних уровней косвенности. Тормоза-то небольшие, но зачем? особенно с учетом того, что сам код становится запутаннее для чтения.